# version pointing to old version even after updating JDK

Tags: java, java-6

I updated my JDK from 1.3 to 1.6 and checked the version using command **java -version** in command prompt after updating the environmental variable entry for **JAVA_HOME** to 1.6 and also I have included the jre-bin path to **PATH** variable, unfortunately **java -version** is still pointing to 1.3. Can anyone please let me know what am I missing here?

I am using windows XP 32 bit.

Comment: have you changed `PATH` variable?

Comment: You should uninstall both Java 1.3 and 6 and install the latest Java 7. Your problem is probably having 1.3 in your PATH before 1.6.

Comment: From Java 1.3, really? [Welcome to the World of Tomorrow](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fw1XJbV2HK0)!

Comment: @PradeepSimha Yes I did, Still no luck. I have updated **JAVA_HOME**, I added JRE lib and JDK lib path in **PATH**, anything else that need to be done?

Comment: I hope you have re-opened the command prompt after setting the environment variables `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli : Yes I did!

Comment: Please add the complete value of the %PATH% to the Question.  The problem is 99% likely to be there ...

Comment: Make sure that your path does not contain jdk 1.3 path after jdk 1.6 path.

Comment: Thank you all for you comments, So there shouldn't be any previous version JRE paths in **PATH**?

Comment: @DSP, yes there shouldn't be any.

Comment: `C:\oracle\ora92\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin` is the content of my **PATH**

Comment: Thank you guys.. Problem solved.. Above **PATH** variable was after editing.. I gave a log off/on to my machine and it worked..

Answer (score 0):

Check "Path" variable. Reference to java 1.3 still left somewhere.

Or maybe you didn't closed/opened cmd, and its still using old JAVA_HOME value?